# Add a value 0 to a variable if EditText is empty

Tags: android, variables

Here's the code I'm using:

`EditText ii1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.i1); 
 String iii1= (String)ii1.getText().toString(); 
 ind1=Double.parseDouble(iii1);`

I need that ind1 acquire value 0 if the EditText is empty.
I already tried using `if (ii1 = "")` and `if (iii1= "")`, but didn't work. How can I do that??

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Got it using this code: `if (iii1.equals("")) {ind1=0;} else {ind1 = Double.parseDouble(iii1);}`

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sould compare strings with

```
iii1.equals("")
```

instead of iii1 = ""

And please, names like "iii1" are suicide sooner or later...

Comment: Great point, names like `iii1` will definitely cause you problems. You might try something like `inputXXX` instead where `XXX` is the name of the thing you are getting input for

Comment: I used your code,but I had to make some changes, check the update. About the `iii1` names, I know it's complicated,but I've already wrote all the code using those, so I decided to let them. On the next time certantly I won't use them hahahahaha Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work `if(ind1 == null || ind1.isEmpty()){ind1=0;}`

Comment: This part : `ind == null ` is not possible, I used the .equals